# Methods for NonlinearModelFit

Tags: mathematical-optimization, fitting, implementation-details

I am using `NonlinearModelFit` for a thesis project.

I get quite different results if I change the Method to LevenbergMarquardt or QuasiNewton or ConjugateGradient and so on. My nonlinear model includes polynomials up to second order and a sigmoid function such as `ArcTan` or `Tanh`. 
I would like to know, which conditions Mathematica uses to choose the best algorithm if I set the `Method` as `Automatic`. It works sometimes, but most of the time it doesn't and I do not have the knowledge to say which method should be the best in my case. Just by trying out, I found `Gradient` and sometimes `ConjugateGradient` to work the best for my purpose.

I also cannot find anywhere on the Internet which exact implementation of these methods is used inside Mathematica and how does it change the results. 
Here maybe an interesting link:
[Optimization Algorithms](http://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/ormp/chap5/sect27.htm)

Thanks!

Comment: If necessary I can post some data and some output from Mathematica.

Comment: Have you read this http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationOverview.html?

Comment: No, I hadn't. Thanks for the link! Probably this will explain some things, but still I think there is nowhere an explanation in the context of Nonlinear Model Fit.

Comment: To the contrary -- this tutorial (note there is also a pdf version you can download and read at your convenience) describes *all* of the optimization technologies -- of which NonlinearModeFit is just one. http://www.wolfram.com/learningcenter/tutorialcollection/UnconstrainedOptimization/UnconstrainedOptimization.pdf

Comment: `NonlinearModelFit` seems to be implemented as a wrapper around `FindFit`, but the latter is kernel code and not accessible for inspection. I would suggest contacting WRI support to ask them which method `Automatic` translates to and under what conditions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Unfortunately the `Method` option is not documented in detail on the [`NonlinearModelFit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html) documentation page.  To summarize what we know so far (comments, documentation, etc.):

`NonlinearModelFit` can either use numerical local optimization, or numerical global optimization.

- Local optimization is the same as used by `FindMinimum` and related functions.  The possible method options are documented in detail [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationOverview.html).  `NonlinearModelFit` will take these options directly.  Example:

  ```
  NonlinearModelFit[..., Method -> {"Newton", "StepControl" -> "TrustRegion"}]
  ```
- Global optimization is the same as used by `NMinimize` and related functions. The available method options are detailed [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationGlobalNumerical.html).  The syntax to use is

  ```
  NonlinearModelFit[..., Method -> {NMinimize, Method -> ...}]
  ```

Further documentation on the constrained optimization is [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationOverview.html).