# How to use this Lorentzian function fit my data, I tried NonlinearModelFit, it always resulted with an error

Tags: fitting, warning-messages

The data is uploaded to Ideone http://ideone.com/ktIbVk , my code is :

```
data = ReadList["-10dBm.txt", {Number, Number}];
model = a/((b - f)/c)^2 + d;
result = NonlinearModelFit[data, model, {a, b, c, {d, 0}}, f];
result1 = result["ParameterTable"];
fitplot1 = plot[result[f], {f, 4.124, 4.133}];
```

the error is :

```
NonlinearModelFit::cvmit:
Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Increase the number of iterations? Look in the documentation: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html

Comment: Add reasonable starting parameters for all parameters.

Comment: Also, your model doesn't look like a Lorentzian? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_line_shape#Line_shape_functions

Comment: My mistake, however the function model I chose is corrected.

Comment: So is it a Lorentzian, or isn't it? Because your function will be $=1/0$ at the point where `f = b`. My answer below is based on it being Lorentzian.

Comment: how to increase the number of iterations? I didn't find an option in your link page. @blochwave

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The timing for the plot from the answer from Alexei can be accelerated by using `Evaluate` and `Prolog` (or `Epilog`).

```
k = 0.725;

model = a*Exp[-Abs[(x - d)]^k/b];

ff = FindFit[data, {model, {a > 0, b > 0, 4.126 < d < 4.1262}},
    {{a, 80}, b, {d, 4.126}}, x] // Quiet;

xmin = Floor[Min[data[[All, 1]]], .001];
xmax = Ceiling[Max[data[[All, 1]]], .001];
ymax = Ceiling[Max[data[[All, 2]]], 5];

Show[{
   ListPlot[data],
   Plot[a*Exp[-Abs[(x - d)]^k/b] /. ff,
    {x, 4.12, 4.13},
    PlotStyle -> Red,
    PlotRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {0, ymax}}]}] //
 Timing
```

[image]

Timing using `Evaluate` to prevent repeated use of `ReplaceAll`

```
Show[{
   ListPlot[data],
   Plot[Evaluate[
     a*Exp[-Abs[(x - d)]^k/b] /. ff],
    {x, 4.12, 4.13},
    PlotStyle -> Red,
    PlotRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {0, ymax}}]}] //
 Timing
```

[image]

Timing using `Prolog` vice `Show` and `ListPlot` with `Evaluate`

```
Plot[Evaluate[
   a*Exp[-Abs[(x - d)]^k/b] /. ff],
  {x, 4.12, 4.13},
  Prolog -> Point[data],
  PlotStyle -> Red,
  PlotRange -> {{xmin, xmax}, {0, ymax}}] //
 Timing
```

[image]

While the difference is trivial in this case, for more complex functions the difference can be significant particularly if the plot is in a `Manipulate`.

Comment: @blochwave - does seem odd. I'll +1 yours to compensate somewhat.

Answer (score 9):

Turns out I've got a bit of spare time, so here goes!

Following the information provided in the [Wikipedia article on spectral lines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_line_shape#Line_shape_functions), the model function you want for a Lorentzian is of the form:

$$
L=\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}
$$

where

$$
x=\frac{A-x}{B}
$$

with $A$ and $B$ as the position of the maximum, and twice the FWHM, respectively.

Now let's look at your model - notice the brackets around the parameter `d` - without it, the function is going to be $=1/0$ at the middle of the peak.

```
model = a/(((b - f)/c)^2 + d);
result = NonlinearModelFit[data, 
   model, {{a, 82.17435}, {b, 4.126155}, {c, 0.000283}, {d, 1.}}, f, 
   MaxIterations -> 500];
result["BestFitParameters"]
fitplot1 = 
 Show[ListPlot[data], 
  Plot[result[f], {f, 4.124, 4.133}, PlotRange -> Full]]

(* {a -> 86.104, b -> 4.12616, c -> 0.000276, d -> 1.05174} *)
```

And this result gives the following graph:

[image]

But what if I try it with different starting parameters?

```
model = a/(((b - f)/c)^2 + d);
result = NonlinearModelFit[data, 
  model, {{a, 82.}, {b, 4.126}, {c, 0.0002}, {d, 2.}}, f, 
  MaxIterations -> 500]
result["BestFitParameters"]
(* {a -> 123.998, b -> 4.12616, c -> 0.000230629, d -> 1.51461}*)
```

This still fits, but the parameters are all very different!

Heck, let's play around with the `Method` options of `NonLinearModelFit`.

I'll use `Method->{NMinimize}` here as per [Methods for NonlinearModelFit](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21823/methods-for-nonlinearmodelfit), to perform a global optimization, with no initial guesses needed.

```
model = a/(((b - f)/c)^2 + d);
result = NonlinearModelFit[data, 
  model, {a, b, c, d}, f, 
  MaxIterations -> 500, Method -> {NMinimize}]
result["BestFitParameters"]
result["AdjustedRSquared"]
result["AIC"]
fitplot1 = 
 Show[ListPlot[data], 
  Plot[result[f], {f, 4.124, 4.133}, PlotRange -> Full]]

(* {a -> 6.14622, b -> 4.12616, c -> 0.00103591, d -> 0.0750752} *)
(* AdjustedRSquared = 0.997582 *)
(* AIC = 142.984 *)
```

Notice how the parameters are again different, but the result looks the same:

[image]

Now let's remove `d` from the equation and replace it with 1.

```
model = a/(((b - f)/c)^2 + 1.);
(* {a -> 81.8689, b -> 4.12616, c -> 0.000283838} *)
(* AdjustedRSquared = 0.997648 *)
(* AIC = 140.984 *)
```

Marginally better.

---

Also, let's put your data here rather than in a file.

```
data = {{4.124, 1.823}, {4.1241, 1.993}, {4.1242, 2.184}, {4.1243, 
   2.403}, {4.1244, 2.612}, {4.1245, 2.919}, {4.1246, 3.257}, {4.1247,
    3.637}, {4.1248, 4.133}, {4.1249, 4.76}, {4.125, 5.506}, {4.1251, 
   6.339}, {4.1252, 7.448}, {4.1253, 9.307}, {4.1254, 
   10.956}, {4.1255, 13.628}, {4.1256, 17.32}, {4.1257, 
   22.68}, {4.1258, 30.794}, {4.1259, 42.704}, {4.126, 
   59.972}, {4.1261, 81.436}, {4.1262, 81.723}, {4.1263, 
   63.309}, {4.1264, 45.292}, {4.1265, 32.623}, {4.1266, 
   24.327}, {4.1267, 18.823}, {4.1268, 14.627}, {4.1269, 
   12.612}, {4.127, 9.732}, {4.1271, 8.272}, {4.1272, 7.902}, {4.1273,
    6.021}, {4.1274, 5.232}, {4.1275, 4.523}, {4.1276, 
   4.023}, {4.1277, 3.602}, {4.1278, 3.212}, {4.1279, 3.025}}
```

Comment: My mistake.I just found it and got the right result. Your model function is right, and thanks for your examples. that is really helpful.

Comment: Glad I could help! If it worked for you, there's a little tick next to my answer for you to accept it, as per: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 k = 0.725;
model = a*Exp[-Abs[(x - d)]^k/b];
ff = FindFit[
  data, {model, {a > 0, b > 0, 4.126 < d < 4.1262}}, {{a, 80}, 
   b, {d, 4.126}}, x]
Show[{

  ListPlot[data],
  Plot[a*Exp[-Abs[(x - d)]^k/b] /. ff, {x, 4.12, 4.13}, 
   PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All]

  }]
```

It looks like the following:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! However, this model function is not what I want, the data is used to described a resonance phenomenon.

Comment: I used Excel to fit the data by using Minimum the difference between the fitted value and the data with "solver", it turned out that the parameter will have the best value "a=82.17436, b=4.126155, c=0.000283, d=0". However when I applied these value as the starting parameters, I could not get the best fit, the result is not right at all, why?

Comment: @Hang Yang First the answer to your first comment: I tried Lorenzian first. In particular, the same type of the model as in the answer of blochwave. It worked poor for me. I see from the answer above that there is a trick giving the solution. However, my experience of fitting shows that the necessity of tricks may mean that the data is poorly described by the model used, and another model should be looked for. That motivated the function I applied. The second question: I did not optimize the model. For example, why k=0.75? It is up to you, if you decide to use this model.