# problems of Lorentizan fit with Nonlinear fit model

Tags: fitting

I tried to do a Lorentzian fit for a Spectroscopy data.I found that I have to actually give the precise value for this fit.[i do not like to call this as fit ,if that is the case]?

Am I missing something here
The notebook , the data and a plot pic from Igor have been added

https://www.transferbigfiles.com/0844eafa-5317-420b-acd6-f9553e283b3e/n9xrkyLWyjM0RLlFGj7TTw2

I appreciate your comments and help, I also want to know is there any other function i can use it for plotting this

Comment: Did you check, for example, [this Q&A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55664/18476)?

Comment: Creating a minimal working example for your problem might result in more responses than just a link to somewhere.

Comment: By the way I do not know how to attach a notebook file and data, and the size of the file is very small. I want to know about this particular situation cause generally nonlinear fitting function in mathematica works just fine

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what is the problem. In your notebook it looks like the NonLinearFit[] finds the local minima of the parameters when using default start values.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is highly localized and probably of no value to future visitors, especially once the provided link is no longer valid.

Comment: [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584/18476)

Comment: Sorry about the Ignorance.

Answer (score 2):

You were very unclear about what your actual question is.  But I'm trying to procrastinate so here's what I would do,

```
data = Get["http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=FeEa2MU9"];
lorentzianModel = y0 - a/(b + (x - x0)^2);
```

I took your CSV file, which you generally can't ask people on this site to download, imported it, and used the command `CopyToClipboard[data[[All,;;2]]]` and then pasted the result into pastebin.com.  That's the easiest way to share example data.

To get the nonlinear fit to work, you need decent guesses for the parameters, which I found by just plotting the model and varying the parameters.

```
fit = NonlinearModelFit[data, 
  lorentzianModel, {{y0, .03}, {a, 5 10^(-7)}, {b, 3 10^-5}, {x0, 
    10.25}}, x]
```

[image]

There is really no benefit to multiplying the frequency axis by 10^10 before fitting, you can just do that later.  So check the results of the fit,

```
fit["ParameterConfidenceIntervalTable"]
```

[image]

and compare them to what you got from Igor,

[image]

and it looks good.  Then plot the results,

```
Show[ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot[fit[x], {x, 10.0, 10.5}, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

[image]

Let me reiterate though, that it is not clear what your question is.

Comment: First of all I am extremely sorry for not making my question very clear, sorry about the ignorance. Thank you so much Jason for clarifying things. I understand my mistake, because of the bad guesses; The code could not find the global minimum, it might have trapped into some minimum, when I computed. Thanks a lot

Comment: No worries, it just seems from the notebook that you got it all worked out fine, so I didn't know where exactly you need help

Comment: But now might be a good time to ask: what were you looking to improve from your code?  I've cleaned it up a bit I think, but in general you had a decent fit to the data

Comment: Essentially I have been trying to make a code in which mathematica automatically detect the guesses for the Lorenztian fit, I realized that it is the x0 which matters the most  , So the code will be $k = Position[data[[All, 2]], Min[data[[All, 2]]]]$ and I have to map this location to put to the fit, by the way it is giving something like (1026). which is the location, How do I use as a parameter in the Nonlinearfit. What i meant to say is how do you remove thebracket of the index location

Comment: Actually, I found that if I didn't put in reasonable guesses for the other parameters, it would have trouble then as well

Comment: For that what I am gonna do is, I will start from a very low number such as , let us say 10^-12 for a and b, y0 I can easily trace from the graph itself. That is the  offset right? Could you please tell me  how to convert the following  (1026)->just the number 1026.

Comment: The problem comes becasue of the starting value, Since the term like 1/(x-x0)^2. It is sort of obvious that this term gives the most problematic part, do not you think Jason?

Comment: I agree that the position of the peak is important, but just play around with the code above and see what comes out if you don't have the a and b numbers in the right order of magnitude.  And not sure what you mean, but something like this?  `{f -> 1026}[[1, 2]]`

Comment: Not exactly, So whenever I try to find the minimum for example--k = Position[data[[All, 2]], Min[data[[All, 2]]]], This gives me the result like the location number in bracket such as (1026). I want to remove the bracket and use as an integer number such k=1026 instead of (1026). So that I can input this k in my code as a parameter.     I will get back to you with the result and share you the code :) and I have not had much experience in any programming language Jason

Comment: I've put about as much time into this one as I can, but look into `Part` - if the number comes back in a bracket (you've put it in parentheses, but I assume you mean curly brackets), then you access it by `[[some number]]`

Comment: data = datasort[[All, ;; 2]]

In[51]:= Min[data[[All, 2]]]

Out[51]= 0.00579802

In[58]:= k = 
 Flatten[Position[data[[All, 2]], Min[data[[All, 2]]]]][[1]]

In[71]:= fit = 
 NonlinearModelFit[data, 
  lorentzianModel, {{y0, 0}, {a, 10^(-12)}, {b, 10^-12}, {x0, 
    data[[k, 1]]}}, x]
Show[ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot[fit[x], {x, 10.0, 10.5}, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> All]]

Out[71]= FittedModel[0.0304754 -6.95515*10^-8/((x-10.2559)^2+3.10265*10^-6)]

Comment: This is what I meant to say

Comment: Essentially for 'a' and 'b', Start from a very small number. That is all

Comment: Once again thanks a lot Jaison for the help