# Default algorithm in NonlinearModelFit

Tags: fitting, implementation-details

Does anyone know the default algorithm used in `NonlinearModelFit`? The documentation gives several possible algorithms, but I can't figure out what it uses if you do not specify the algorithm.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: The Answer to [21823](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21823/methods-for-nonlinearmodelfit) has some information.

Answer (score 13):

From [Introduction to Local Minimization](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationIntroductionLocalMinimization.html#509267359):

> **With Method -> Automatic**, the Wolfram Language uses the quasi-Newton method unless the problem is structurally a sum of squares, in which case **the Levenberg-Marquardt variant of the Gauss-Newton method is used**.

To confirm, I use the first example in [FindFit >> Options >> Method](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindFit.html) and compare the output for various settings for the `Method` option:

> Possible settings for Method include "ConjugateGradient", "Gradient", "LevenbergMarquardt", "Newton", "NMinimize", and "QuasiNewton", with the default being Automatic.

```
model = a Exp[-b (x - c)^2] + d Sin[ω x + ϕ];
data = Table[{x, model /. {a -> 2, b -> 1, c -> 0, d -> 2, ω -> 0.67, ϕ -> 0.1}}, 
           {x, -5, 5, .1}] + RandomReal[.25, 101];

methods = {Automatic, "ConjugateGradient", "Gradient", "LevenbergMarquardt",
           "Newton", "NMinimize", "QuasiNewton"};

nlms = Quiet@ NonlinearModelFit[data, model, {a, b, c, d, ω, ϕ}, x, 
                 Method -> #]["ParameterTable"] & /@ methods; 
Grid[Partition[Labeled[#, #2, Top] & @@@ Transpose[{nlms, methods}], 3], Spacings -> {5, 5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much.

Comment: @user3037237, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.

Comment: How to tell if Mathematica thinks your problem is a sum of squares? is there anyway to query the fit to ask what it used?

Comment: @TomMozdzen, good question. I don't know the answer ottomh.

Comment: @kglr I suppose I could use your code above and substitute my fitting equation and a sample data set and compare outputs as you have done above. Finding out should be a single simple command I would think. Do you know where the various methods are documented? I haven't found the page where they give you the full list of options.

Comment: @TomMozdzen, the tutorial  [introduction to local minimization](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationIntroductionLocalMinimization.html#509267359) lists only 5 methods. There may be more information in various parts of [tutorial - constrained optimization](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationOverview.html)