# Counterpart of Maple's LSSolve in Mathematica

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization, maple

I am a great fan of Mathematica. Unfortunately, due to some specific tasks I had to move to Maple. I think it's my lack of info that is not letting me do those tasks. That is why I am asking some command replacements from you guys. I code some mesh free methods like Galerkin and spectral methods. They use a trial solution which contains some constants. After some treatment the problem gets converted to an over-determined system of algebraic equations. Maple has a command LSSolve to determine a best possible solution to that over-determined system. Can you please tell me its alternative in Mathematica. I really need it to bring all my coding back to Mathematica.
my equations.

```
eq1 = -.3007024038*c[2]^2 + (-0.4990858944 10^-2 - .3007024038*c[1])*
c[2];
eq2 = -.2004682692*c[2]^2 + (-0.2495429472 10^-2 - .1503512019*c[1])*
c[2];
eq3 = -.1503512019*c[2]^2 + (-0.1663619648 10^-2 - .1002341346*c[1])*
c[2];
eq4 = c[0] + c[1] + c[2] - 1;
```

PS
Here is a snap of the calculations on MAPLE
[image]

Comment: Perhaps [`LeastSquares`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LeastSquares.html) is what you are looking for in MMA.

Comment: thank you for you reply but i am afraid its not LeastSquares I am after. According to the documentation it solve linear systems. While I mostly encounter with nonlinear equations. As far as LSSolve is concerned it minimizes the Squared residual Error. I have tried to do it myslef in Mathematics but in vain.

Comment: Then we need more information. Gives us an example of a (small!) problem you solve with `LSSolve`, together with the output you obtain from Maple. I do not use Maple, so I am only going with the information included in its [documentation for `LSSolve`](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=Optimization%2FLSSolve). If you don't provide more details, then only people intimately familiar with both systems will be able to answer your question. Alternatively, you could always use `NMinimize` etc to explicitly minimize a sum of squares.

Comment: In priciple, that's a task for `NonlinearModelFit`. I also recall to have read <s>somewhere</s> [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/73587/38178) that `FindMinimum` switches automatically to the Levenberg-Marquardt mathod (a minor modification of Gauss-Newton method) if it detects that the objective function is a sum of squares... So give it a try with either method.

Comment: I am sorry the internet here is making some problems. I will soon post some sample equations and their maple output.

Comment: Please post the code text so we can test them easily.

Comment: I am on to it. please wait for a while. I am uploading it.

Comment: text added. Thank you all for your support. It was a major internet breakdown that slowed every thing. I have uploaded a smaller version of my code. I general the equations I encounter are too many and much complicated.

Comment: Your question has votes to be placed  [on-hold](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) because its was consider unclear. Please [edit] your question to [improve it](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and make it specific and well structured with all the information needed to reproduce and fix your problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the document of `LSSolve`:

> The `LSSolve` command solves a least-squares (LS) problem, which
>   involves computing the minimum of a real-valued objective function
>   having the form $$\frac{1}{2}(f_1(x)^2+f_2(x^2)+…+f_q(x)^2)$$ where
>   $x$ is a vector of problem.

So its analog in *Mathematica* seems to be `FindMinimum` with a specific function to be minimized. We should be able to obtain (almost) the same result with:

```
Clear@lSSolve
lSSolve[obj_List, constr___, x_, opt : OptionsPattern[FindMinimum]] := 
 FindMinimum[{1/2 obj^2 // Total, constr}, x, opt]
lSSolve[obj_, rest__] := lSSolve[{obj}, rest]
```

Let's test with the examples given in the document and your question:

## Case 1

*Maple*:

```
LSSolve([x-2, x-6, x-9]);
(*     [12.3333333333333321, [x = 5.66666666666667]]*)
```

*Mathematica*:

```
lSSolve[{x - 2, x - 6, x - 9}, x]
(* {12.3333, {x -> 5.66667}} *)
```

## Case 2

*Maple*:

```
LSSolve([x^3-2, x^2-6, x^2-9], initialpoint = {x = 1});
(*           [27.5839512531713, [x = 1.75156454919679]]*)
```

*Mathematica*:

```
lSSolve[{x^3 - 2, x^2 - 6, x^2 - 9}, {x, 1}]
(* {27.584, {x -> 1.75156}} *)
```

## Case 3

*Maple*:

```
LSSolve([x-1, y-1, z-1], {x <= 0, 6*x+3*y <= 1}, initialpoint = {x = -1, y = 1});
(*  [0.711111111111111138, [x = -0.0666666666666667, y = 0.466666666666667, z = 1.]]*)
```

*Mathematica*:

```
lSSolve[{x - 1, y - 1, z - 1}, {x <= 0, 6 x + 3 y <= 1}, {{x, -1}, {y, 1}, z}]
(* {0.711111, {x -> -0.0666676, y -> 0.466668, z -> 1.}} *)
```

## Case 4

*Maple*:

```
LSSolve([x-1], {(x+1)^2 <= 0});
(*        [1.99998465585440166, [x = -0.999992327912486]]*)
```

*Mathematica*:

```
lSSolve[x - 1, (x + 1)^2 <= 0, x]
(* {2., {x -> -1.}} *)
```

## Case 5: Example in your question

```
eq1 = -0.3007024038 c[2]^2 + (-(0.4990858944/10^2) - 0.3007024038 c[1]) c[2];
eq2 = -0.2004682692 c[2]^2 + (-(0.2495429472/10^2) - 0.1503512019 c[1]) c[2];
eq3 = -0.1503512019 c[2]^2 + (-(0.1663619648/10^2) - 0.1002341346 c[1]) c[2];
eq4 = c[0] + c[1] + c[2] - 1;
lSSolve[{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4}, c /@ Range[0, 2]]
(* {1.58921*10^-33, {c[0] -> 1.0166, c[1] -> -0.0165973, c[2] -> 7.45058*10^-9}} *)
```

Slightly different, but according to objective function value, result of *Mathematica* is better.

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess this is what I was looking for.

Comment: @naveed There's a bug in my previous implementation, now it's fixed and result of **case 4** is also (almost) the same as that of _Maple_.

Answer (score 5):

Is this not what you want ?

```
In[6]:= NMinimize[eq1^2 + eq2^2 + eq3^2 + eq4^2, {c[0], c[1], c[2]}]

Out[6]= {1.94723*10^-27, {c[0] -> 1.01633, c[1] -> -0.0163307, 
  c[2] -> 4.71816*10^-10}}
```

Comment: Thank you. A vote up for you.

Comment: I have got better results (In the implementation of my complete code) by combining the both techniques. I used Lotus's Nminimize with xzczd definition of LSSolve and got the solutions that agree very well with the exact solutions of actual solutions. I was confused in selecting the answer but then i thought xzczd answer in more general. I am thankful to all of you for helping me out.