# FindFit with a sophisticated function (integral)

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations, fitting, polynomials, approximation

I am trying to find a fit to the distribution function (empiricial data) in terms of a function which is itself an integral of a product of two simpler functions (two polynomials), that is the model. In particular, I observe T(x) and the model is that $$T(x) \approx \int_0^xF(\frac{x-y}{1-y})g(y)dy $$

My assumption is that $F(.)$ and $g(.)$ are polynomial functions. And so my problem would be to find the best fit polynomial functions, i.e. to assume that $F(.)= k_1+a_1 (\frac{x-y}{1-y})+ b_1 (\frac{x-y}{1-y})^2$ and similarly $g(.)=k_2+a_2 y + b_2 y^2$ and let `FindFit` run.

Here is the data (just a small sample)

```
data={{0.002, 4}, {0.01, 5}, {0.02, 1}, {0.025, 1}, {0.0333, 1}, {0.05, 
1}, {0.0905, 1}, {0.09995, 1}, {0.105, 1}, {0.114, 1}, {0.2, 
5}, {0.222, 2}, {0.25, 1}, {0.3, 1}, {0.35, 1}, {0.4, 7}, {0.5, 
29}, {0.501, 2}, {0.505, 2}, {0.51, 1}, {0.52, 1}, {0.55, 
1}, {0.55555, 1}, {0.6, 12}, {0.64, 2}, {0.65, 5}, {0.666, 1}, {0.7,
18}, {0.73, 1}, {0.74, 1}, {0.75, 30}, {0.76, 3}, {0.77266, 
2}, {0.775, 1}, {0.8, 57}, {0.801, 2}, {0.8018, 1}, {0.802, 
1}, {0.81, 1}, {0.81554, 1}, {0.82, 3}, {0.825, 1}, {0.82888, 
1}, {0.83, 1}, {0.84, 4}, {0.85, 30}, {0.859, 1}, {0.86, 3}, {0.861,
1}, {0.862, 1}, {0.875, 7}, {0.88, 8}, {0.888, 2}, {0.9, 
46}, {0.901, 3}, {0.9018, 1}, {0.902, 1}, {0.9022, 1}, {0.9026, 
1}, {0.9027, 1}, {0.904, 1}, {0.9094, 1}, {0.91, 2}, {0.9202, 
1}, {0.925, 1}, {0.926, 1}, {0.93, 1}, {0.94, 2}, {0.95, 5}, {0.96, 
3}, {0.976, 1}, {0.98, 1}, {0.995, 1}, {1., 11}};
```

I have been trying to solve this pretty naively as follows:

```
D=SmoothKernelDistribution[data, 0.02];    
FindFit[CDF[D, x], 
Integrate[(a1 ((x - y)/(1 - y))^2 + b1 ((x - y)/(1 - y)) + 
   k1) (a2 y^2 + b2 y + k2), {y, 0, x}], {a1, b1, k1, a2, b2, 
k2}, {(x - y)/(1 - y), y}]
```

However I got the error: "(-y+x)/(1-y) is not a valid variable". I am sure that I need more sophisticated approach, but which steps would be there I am pretty lost...

(I did not specify in my code the domains (both x and y belong to [0,1]), but I doubt that this is of any relevance at this stage.)

I would appreciate any hints how to proceed!

Comment: I'm not quite following.  Are the pairs of numbers of the form {$x$,$T(x)$} ?  And why are the $T(x)$ always integers?

Comment: I provided in fact the raw data, frequency of the observed outcomes, where the first element of the row is the outcome, the second is its frequency. But T(x) is the CDF of outcomes (I just did not want to impose how we got it). So T(x) can come from D = SmoothKernelDistribution[data, 0.02];

Comment: PS: thank you for editing and clarifying question. I hope I am more clear now?

Comment: OUPS! Corrected the code!

Comment: Some problems: c should be x in your definition of g? D is a protected symbol in Mathematica. Your use of CDF doesn't make any sense, as you defined D as a multivariate kernel for some reason.

Comment: Thanks Paw, I corrected, it should be "y" (and it got lost in my translation from my internal notation...)

Comment: If $T(X)$ is the observed CDF of a random variable from any continuous distribution, then $T(X) \sim U(0,1)$ (i.e., a uniform distribution from 0 to 1) and no fitting is required to know the distribution of $T(X)$.  So, I'm still not understanding things.  Is $T(X)$ an observed CDF (cumulative distribution function)?

Comment: Yes Jim, T(X) is the observed empirically CDF. However in my model F(.) and g(.) are unknown and has to be calibrated to match the observed T(.) according to the above relationship. So my approach is suppose that F(.) and g(.) are polynomials and then to find the coefficients with "find fit".

Comment: I think you need the triplet {$x$,$T(x)$,frequency} to be able to perform the estimation of the coefficients of $F(.)$ and $g(.)$.  But if what you've given so far is {$T(x)$,frequency}, then a plot of that data shows something very far from a uniform distribution if there were indeed random samples from a random variable with distribution function $T(x)$.

Comment: I see the confusion, no in fact I have given $\{x, frequency\}$, while $T(x)$ is cumulative distribution that one gets uniquely from the frequency... I shall update my post to make it more clear..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `datatest` has one too many parenthesis.

Dont use `func`, replace it with the evaluated integral.

```
Integrate[(a ((x - y)/(1 - y))^2 + b ((x - y)/(1 - y)) + 
    c) (d y^2 + e y + f), {y, 0, x}, Assumptions -> {0 < x < 1}]
(* 
1/6 x (6 (c f + b (d + e + f) + a (4 d + 3 e + 2 f)) - 
    3 (-c e + b (d + e) + a (8 d + 5 e + 2 f)) x + (2 a - b + 
       2 c) d x^2) + (-b (d + e + f) + 
    a (-2 f + e (-3 + x) + 2 d (-2 + x))) (-1 + x) Log[1 - x] *)
```

Now run `FindFit`

```
sol = FindFit[datatest,
  1/6 x (6 (c f + b (d + e + f) + a (4 d + 3 e + 2 f)) - 
      3 (-c e + b (d + e) + a (8 d + 5 e + 2 f)) x + (2 a - b + 
         2 c) d x^2) + (-b (d + e + f) + 
      a (-2 f + e (-3 + x) + 2 d (-2 + x))) (-1 + x) Log[1 - x], {a, 
   b, c, d, e, f}, x, Method -> NMinimize, 
  NormFunction -> (Norm[#, Infinity] &)]

(* {a -> -2.70862, b -> 0.555548, c -> -0.243013, 
 d -> -0.124391, e -> -0.310328, f -> -0.516147} *)
```

Plot the results

```
Show[
 ListPlot[datatest],
 Plot[Evaluate[func[a, b, c, d, e, f, x] /. sol], {x, 0, 1}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you very much! It is all super helpful. One thing that I am wondering about -- could we be sure that the found parameters (found with Findfit) are "global" minimizers? (E.g. because we used "NMinimize" method, which strives to find the global max/min). And if we cannot be sure, is there a way to double check it somehow? Thank you!

Comment: @Cactusenok You can find more information on optimization and global max/min [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21823/methods-for-nonlinearmodelfit)

Answer (score 3):

One can gain insight into a problem of this sort by using a forward model with known parameters and running `FindFit` (or something similar) with perfect data.

When we integrate your equation

```
Integrate[(a1 ((x - y)/(1 - y))^2 + b1 ((x - y)/(1 - y)) + 
    k1) (a2 y^2 + b2 y + k2), {y, 0, x}]
```

the solution is

```
1/6 x (6 (b1 (a2 + b2) + (b1 + k1) k2 + a1 (4 a2 + 3 b2 + 2 k2)) - 
    3 (b1 (a2 + b2) - b2 k1 + a1 (8 a2 + 5 b2 + 2 k2)) x + 
    a2 (2 a1 - b1 + 2 k1) x^2) + (-b1 (a2 + b2 + k2) + 
    a1 (-2 k2 + b2 (-3 + x) + 2 a2 (-2 + x))) (-1 + x) Log[1 - x]
```

provided x < 1.

Next we will make some synthetic data. We will set all of the coefficients to 1 (or any number that is reasonable for your equation).

```
1/6 x (6 (b1 (a2 + b2) + (b1 + k1) k2 + a1 (4 a2 + 3 b2 + 2 k2)) - 
     3 (b1 (a2 + b2) - b2 k1 + a1 (8 a2 + 5 b2 + 2 k2)) x + 
     a2 (2 a1 - b1 + 2 k1) x^2) + (-b1 (a2 + b2 + k2) + 
     a1 (-2 k2 + b2 (-3 + x) + 2 a2 (-2 + x))) (-1 + x) Log[
    1 - x] /.
 {a1 -> 1, b1 -> 1, k1 -> 1, a2 -> 1, b2 -> 1, k2 -> 1}
```

results in

```
1/6 x (78 - 48 x + 3 x^2) + (-1 + x) (-8 + 2 (-2 + x) + x) Log[1 - x]
```

and now we make the data. We'll set the range to get approximately the same number of points as your data.

```
data = Map[{#, 
    1/6 # (78 - 48 # + 3 #^2) + (-1 + #) (-8 + 2 (-2 + #) + #) Log[
       1 - #]} &, Range[0.02, 1, 0.013]]
```

This has 76 points (your data had 74 points). A plot of the data looks like:

```
ListPlot[data]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now let's run `FindFit`. All of the starting values will be set to 1 except one.

```
FindFit[data, 
 1/6 x (6 (b1 (a2 + b2) + (b1 + k1) k2 + a1 (4 a2 + 3 b2 + 2 k2)) - 
     3 (b1 (a2 + b2) - b2 k1 + a1 (8 a2 + 5 b2 + 2 k2)) x + 
     a2 (2 a1 - b1 + 2 k1) x^2) + (-b1 (a2 + b2 + k2) + 
     a1 (-2 k2 + b2 (-3 + x) + 2 a2 (-2 + x))) (-1 + x) Log[1 - x],
 {{a1, 1}, {b1, 2}, {k1, 1}, {a2, 1}, {b2, 1}, {k2, 1}}, x]
```

The result is

```
{a1 -> 0.659693, b1 -> 0.659693, k1 -> 0.659693, a2 -> 1.51586, 
 b2 -> 1.51586, k2 -> 1.51586}
```

Note that it doesn't really match at all. From this I infer that this is a poor resolution problem.

If one simply replaces `FindFit` with `NonlinearModelFit` you can get an estimate of the correlation between parameters. For this problem there is a high degree of correlation indicating that the parameters are not independent.

Bottom line, you will not be able to extract six parameters for this problem. You will need to reduce the degrees of freedom by setting one or more parameters to fixed values.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jack for the answer, it was helpful. I have been thinking about what I really need to find, and so just would like to re-state my question better and also to show what were my attemps (only partially successful) to solve things on my own.

I am trying to find a fit to the distribution function (empiricial data) in terms of a function which is itself an integral of a product of two simplier functions. In particular, I observe T(x) (this is already the empirical CDF) and the model is that this $$T(x) \approx \int_0^xF(\frac{x-y}{1-y})g(y)dy $$

So I need to find $F(.)$ and $g(.)$ that woud fit the observed $T(x)$ (according to the above relationship) the best. "The best" in terms of distance uniform distance.

Moreover $F(.)$ is constrainted to be non-decreasing mapping [0,1] -> [0,1] (in fact it is a CDF of $\frac{x-y}{1-y}$), while $g(.)$ is such that $\int_0^1 g(s)ds=1$

One approach would be to try to find the fit in terms of the polynomial functions, i.e. to assume that $F(.)= k_1+a_1 (\frac{x-y}{1-y})+ b_1 (\frac{x-y}{1-y})^2$ and similarly $g(.)=k_2+a_2 y + b_2 y^2$ and let `FindFit` run. (Let us forget for the moment about constraints).

Here is the data for $T(x)$ (just a small sample)

```
datatest={{{0.097, 0.0389972}, {0.117, 0.0473538}, {0.14, 0.0473538}, 
 {0.222, 0.0668524}, {0.234, 0.0668524}, {0.262, 0.0696379},
 {0.297,0.0696379}, {0.33, 0.0724234}, {0.423, 0.0947075}, {0.5, 
 0.181058}, {0.522, 0.192201}, {0.605, 0.231198}, {0.617,0.231198},
{0.673, 0.253482}, {0.686, 0.253482}, {0.748,0.309192}, {0.757,
0.392758}, {0.851, 0.696379}, {0.867,0.713092}, {0.89, 0.760446}}};
```

Following suggestion of Jack I tried to implement this as follows:

```
func[a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ, 
    e_?NumericQ,f_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ] := 
 Integrate[(a ((x - y)/(1 - y))^2 + b ((x - y)/(1 - y)) + c) (d y^2 +
    e y + f), {y, 0, x}, Assumptions -> {0 < x < 1}];
FindFit[datatest, func[a, b, c, d, e, f, x], {a, b, c, d, e, f}, x, 
Method -> NMinimize, NormFunction -> (Norm[#, Infinity] &)]
```

This gives me an error message ("*FindFit::nrlnum:*") I just wonder why, as it seems to me to be exactly the steps as before (done by Jack), integrate and then evaluate FindFit?

And to complicate things further, I have been trying instead of polynomials to use $F(.)$ and $g(.)$ that each would be be a mixture of Beta Distributions.

```
F[w1_, alfa1_, beta1_, alfa2_, beta2_] := 
MixtureDistribution[{w1, (1 - w1)}, {BetaDistribution[alfa1, beta1], 
BetaDistribution[alfa2, beta2]}];

g[ww1_, alfaa1_, betaa1_, alfaa2_, betaa2_] := 
MixtureDistribution[{ww1, (1 - ww1)}, {BetaDistribution[alfaa1, 
betaa1], BetaDistribution[alfaa2, betaa2]}];

func2[w1_, alfa1_, beta1_, alfa2_, beta2_, ww1_, alfaa1_, betaa1_, 
alfaa2_, betaa2_, x_] := 
Integrate[CDF[F[w1, alfa1, beta1, alfa2, beta2, (x - y)/(1 - y)]]*
PDF[g[ww1, alfaa1, betaa1, alfaa2, betaa2], y], {y, 0, x}, 
Assumptions -> {0 < x < 1}]

FindFit[datatest, 
func2[w1, alfa1, beta1, alfa2, beta2, ww1, alfaa1, betaa1, alfaa2, 
betaa2, y], {w1, alfa1, beta1, alfa2, beta2, ww1, alfaa1, betaa1, 
alfaa2, betaa2}, y, Method -> NMinimize, NormFunction -> (Norm[#, Infinity] &)]
```

It ends up with a bunch of errors as well (*"NIntegrate::inumr:"*)...

I will be grateful for any hint for how to make it work..

Comment: Evaluate the integral and then define 'func' in terms of the evaluated integral. If you don't you will re-evaluate the integral each time 'func' is run which can be prohibitively slow.

Comment: Yes, I have realized this now.. Thank you.